# Manipulating JSON from PHP in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, api

I am currently using HTML/PHP to get a JSON file from an API. I then want to manipulate the JSON file in JavaScript and display certain elements of the JSON on the page. I can see that the JSON is being bought back correctly, but I cannot save the JSON into a JavaScript variable after this. My code is below.

```
<?php

$pokemon = $_POST['pokemon'];
$siteaddressAPI = "http://pokeapi.co/api/v1/game/" . $pokemon . "/";
$data = file_get_contents($siteaddressAPI);

echo($data)

?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<body>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p>Created: <span id="created"></span><br></p> 
    <script>
        var txt = <?php echo ($data); ?>;
        obj = JSON.parse(txt);
        document.write("<p>Created: " + obj.created + "</p>");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: I have just noticed my lack of ' ' around my txt variable, this has now been fixed but the issue remains.

Comment: You don’t need `JSON.parse`, remove it. (And rename your variable `txt` to `obj` in the first place, because that is what you are getting when your JSON code gets interpreted by the JS engine.)

Comment: Thats great, thank you! the main issue I have now is that if I document.write or document.getElementById to output certain information in the JSON file, it all comes out as 'undefined'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of the output of the API is:

```
{"created": "2013-11-03T19:31:10.975452", "generation": 1, "id": 1, "modified": "2013-11-03T19:31:10.975393", "name": "Red(jpn)", "release_year": 1996, "resource_uri": "/api/v1/game/1/"}
```

You don’t need JSON.parse, remove it. (And rename your variable txt to obj in the first place, because that is what you are getting when your JSON code gets interpreted by the JS engine.)

```
var obj = <?php echo ($data); ?>;
document.write("<p>Created: " + obj.created + "</p>");
```

An example is shown with the console below:

[image]

Comment: That's great, thank you! the main issue I have now is that if I document.write or document.getElementById to output certain information in the JSON file, it all comes out as 'undefined'.

Comment: So the exact line `document.write("<p>Created: " + obj.created + "</p>");` returns `Created: undefined`? Did you make sure that you didn't have the JSON.parse?

Comment: The JSON.parse is gone now. the new line is `document.write("<p>Created: " + obj.created + "</p>");`.

Comment: Can you provide the value of `$pokemon`? Also make sure the previous line is `var obj = <?php echo $data; ?>;`, Juan Mendes corrected my typo.

Comment: The value of Pokemon is any number between 1 - 15. After removing he brackets and apostrophes from `var obj = '<?php echo ($data;) ?>';` it now works, and is successfully allowing me to display the JSON data on screen the way I want. Thank you very much.